# Using least squares, find the expression of a plane $z=f(x,y) \,$ that is the best fit for a series of points.

Tags: statistics, random-variables, least-squares

Using least squares, find the expression of a plane $z=f(x,y) \,$, that **passes through the origin**

and is the best fit for the following points:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
f(x,y) & 5.7 & 3.75 & 8.9  \\ \hline
x & 1 & 0 & 1.5  \\ \hline
y & 1 & 0.5 & 1.5  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The values of z have a **dispersion** of 0.5 and the variables x and y are measured with no error.

So, first of all, what does it mean when it says dispersion?. As it could be the variance or the standard deviation.

Second, the way I tried to find the plane is using **linear** least squares ($\vec{z} = \vec{\eta} + \vec{\epsilon}$, where $\vec{\eta}=A\vec{x}$).

Since the ecuation of a plane is $z=f(x,y)=Ax + By + C \,$; I wrote the desing matrix like this:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1   & 1   & 1 \\
0   & 0.5 & 1 \\
1.5 & 1.5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and then used the least square method but don't where to use the fact that the plane has to pass through the origin. Any advice is welcome. Thanks

Comment: The fact is that there no C if the plane passes through the origin. If it wasn't so, there would be no need to do regression, since a plane through 3 points is well defined.

Comment: That makes sense, so the only thing would be to form the design matrix without the column of ones? Another thing, dispersion is the same as the standard deviation? Thanks

Comment: yes, without the column of ones (C is not a parameter to optimize, it is simply null). yes, usual understanding of dispersion is what std. dev is measuring, in this case should be the expected error on $z$ measument, but don't understand what it is given for.

Comment: because to calculate the estimate of $\vec{x}$ I need the covariance matrix, since  $\vec{x}=(A'PA)^{-1}A'P\vec{Y}$ where P is the inverse of the covariance matrix and $\vec{Y}$ in this case is $\vec{z}$